# Authenticator app not showing code for Tenant

Tags: android, authentication, admin, activeadmin, activesupport

I lost my login data on my authenticator app. I can't login my developer account because I'm not receiving the code to login on my authenticator app. Please help.

Thank you!

I tried to login into my developer account. The MFA code isn't popping on the authenticator app.